# Unable to draw rasters correctly on leaflet (Y axis mismatch) - issue with projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, netcdf, leaflet-r, rstudio

I am struggling to project ALL rasters that were extracted from netcdf files to be drawn on a leaflet map in RStudio.

There doesn't seem to be any projection or matching issues if I use these rasters in ArcGIS Pro.

Initially, the rasters were not automatically matching the leaflet backdrop but instead they were being displayed as a tiny dot at the origin point near Africa.

After editing the extent and projections as below:
extent(crop_x9) <- extent(-20037508.34, 20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34)
extent(crop_x16) <- extent(-20037508.34, 20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34)

projection(crop_x9) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:3857")
projection(crop_x16) <- CRS("+init=EPSG:3857")

I finally managed to display them, but the matching is now very poor, particularly with the y axis.

[image: the output]

I have tried forcing leaflet options to show the leaflet backdrop map with different projections (e.g.:
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.EPSG3857"))) %>%
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(crs = leafletCRS(crsClass = "L.CRS.EPSG4326")))

and changing the projection for the rasters to match the other options too, with no improvement.

If it helps troubleshooting, below are the initial extent and projection of all rasters that I am trying to display in leaflet, before any transformation:

extent(crop_x9)
class      : Extent
xmin       : -180
xmax       : 180
ymin       : -90
ymax       : 90

projection(crop_x9)
"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.